# Jenkins node select with parameter

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have two Jenkins nodes, but only one node can be ran on special parameter, how do I add restriction to the master that if the parameter was set to true the job will run on target node?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure to accept a parameter that indicate if its special or not.
In jenkins groovy job just use a conditional if to check if parameter is send as special one or its normal accordingly you can create a new variable like

```
def Agent_Var = Special_Agent (The label of special agent)
```

Note - please configure label for the agents to determine which agent to use.

after setting up Agent_Var variable you can define Agent_Var label in pipeline as below -

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "$Agent_Var " }
```